# How to combine two tensors of different shapes in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, concatenation, tensor

I am currently doing this:

```
repeat_vals = [x.shape[0] // pfinal.shape[0]] + [-1] * (len(pfinal.shape) - 1)
            
x = torch.cat((x, pfinal.expand(*repeat_vals)), dim=-1)
```

the shape of x is[91,6] and of final is[6,6]
but I am getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (15) must match the existing size (6) at non-singleton dimension 0.  Target sizes: [15, -1].  Tensor sizes: [6, 6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expand non-singleton values. Furthermore, you cannot enforce `len(x)` to be a multiple of `len(pfinal)`, so instead, depending on your needs, you could more over the desired number and then slice away the excess. Something that you can modify to fit your needs:

```
>>> reps = len(x) // len(pfinal) + 1
>>> res = pfinal.repeat(reps, *[1]*(pfinal.ndim - 1))[:len(x)]
```